# how do i fix qlik sense/qlik view "The requested resource cannot be found." when trying to export data

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I'm new to qlik - having been handed over a project from someone else.

Qlik has been used primarily as a report generator.   I've got a sheet that I right click on and export data - and has been working fine - but now that it's over 1 million rows - the export data takes a really long time and when it finally says "here's a link to download your exported data" - regardless of whether I click on that link immediately, or wait a bit and then click it, it always just says "The requested resource cannot be found."   Every time.

This sheet was working fine with about 800,000 rows, and other sheets in the same app still work fine - so it's definitely just the volume - feels like I'm going over some "report will be available for this long" type time limit and qlik is just deleting it immediately upon creation.

I've no idea how to even begin troubleshooting/fixing this - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is that you are reaching some timeout and/or limit - memory or file size.

Few things on top of my head:

- [NPrinting](https://www.qlik.com/us/products/nprinting) is used for such type of tasks. The downside is that there is a cost involved (you'll have to purchase license)
- Depends on your data but you can export/store data during the reload process as csv (`STORE MyTable INTO ..\Ouptut\MyCSVFile.csv (txt);`)
- Write script that connects to the `Qlik Sense` app ([Engine JSON-RPC API](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/May2021/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/Sense_EngineAPI/introducing-engine-API.htm)) and traverse through the required table(s) data and store the response in whatever format you want